# Angular application doesn't work on iPhone/Safari 5.1.7

Tags: javascript, iphone, angularjs, web, safari

Currently am developing a big project in AngularJS(version 1.3X), Bootstrap(3.3.1), animate.css and few other libraries.
I do test my application on different devices via Google Chrome Developers mode and on few browsers like Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Safari(for Windows7).

I also have possibility to perform tests on Android device and iPhone.
For some strange reason my application seems to work on every device except for iPhone 5 with Safari 5.1.7(when using same Safari but on Windows7 it does work).

Has anyone before stumbled uppon similar problem?

@EDIT
Sorry, forgot to mention what is actually happening.
When I try to press button that's supposed to toggle (using jQuery, I know it should be done via ui-routing, but that's how my boss wants it)  portion of the view (panel) it does not work. Buttons do not perform any actions. There is no reaction.

Comment: What is actually happening ?

Comment: @Okazari, I have updated my question